# Fastest / better way to get rows of information from sqlite to pandas

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I have information in sqlite which I am importing into pandas using:

```
def get_data(db, id, limit, offset):
    cnx = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/%s' %(db+'.db'))
    a = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM %s LIMIT %s OFFSET %d" %(id, limit, offset), cnx)
    return a
    cnx.close
```

In order to get all the rows which equal a certain code across the database I am importing all the tables into one pandas dataframe and then searching from there. This works fine but is there a better / quicker way?

```
id_import = ['id1_SH', 'id2_SH', 'id3_SH']
all_ids = []

for i in id_import:
    data = get_data(i, 5, 0)
    all_ids.append(data)
all_ids = pd.concat(all_ids)

all_ids

all_ids[all_ids.index.isin(['M4052542', 'M4009722'])]
```

Comment: Your approach looks good to me. You can try optimize it depending on what are you going to do with `all_ids`. For example you can filter ID's during the reading from SQLite...

Comment: I have about 20 ids that are consistently checked so, now that you have said it out loud, would prob make sense to have one one dataframe continually referenced as opposed to consistently going back and drawing data from sqlite. If you have a different opinion please let me know...